# How does firefox know when to display a green bar?

Tags: certificates

Recently I've been working on creating a self signed CA and had some success. 
Now I have a working CA with valid CRL server. The root CA has been deployed to all of my devices and had no problem.

But I have a question, I would like to sign SSL certs to display the green bar like other commercial EV SSL products. I looked into the parameters of those EV SSL certs but could not find any relevant variables. So I assume that the browsers have a separate way of knowing when to display the green bar.

I would like to know what it is and how to change it, especially for Firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated by [James F](https://serverfault.com/users/8047/james-f) in an [excellent answer](https://serverfault.com/a/48129/140016) at Server Fault:

> The way that EV SSL certificates work is to stick an authority-specific OID in the certificate policies extension field of the cert (which is a standard X.509 certificate otherwise).
>
> ...the reference OIDs for each authority are shipped as part of the browser's root store of certificates. The user interfaces don't let you add a new CA and say "this is an EV capable CA and the UID is a.b.c.d.e.f".
>
> I suppose it might be possible to build an open-source browser from source, adding your own CA's cert along with its EV oid to the root store, but you haven't really achieved much by doing so. **The browser would no longer be compliant with the CA/Browser forum EV guidelines** (which limit the EV-capable authorities).
>
> Wikipedia has more info on EV certificates here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate

<sub>Sure, this looks like a conspiracy by CAs (and browser devs). Yet, this arrangement makes for a less chaotic world.</sub>

NOTE: You can issue an EV cert with a green bar in Firefox, but you have to get a debugging build according to http://sidstamm.com/evssl-trust/firefox-evca.html

Getting others to trust your browser may be a bit difficult, though.